# The type or namespace name not found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code write in C# which I use in unity5 but because was for a old version of unity I have a little problem.

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name `collider' could not be
>   found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Code is

```
Vector3 worldPosition = GetComponent<collider>().bounds.center + Vector3.up * collider.bounds.size.y * 0.5f;
```

If you want a perspective of code [here](http://pastebin.com/hvWD17Du).

Comment: It should be with a capital C=> `Collider`

Comment: Please, read tag descriptions before you use them. `unity` has nothing to do with Unity game engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that you do not have a type or namespace called `collider` within the solution.

I noticed from your PasteBin solution you are using `typeof(Collider)`. Therefore I think the type is `Collider` not `collider`.

Also you may need an instance of this object in order to use the properties:

```
Collider collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
```

Then you can use the `collider` object to access the properties size and center.

Comment: In Unity, getting a component is a matter of calling the used `GetComponent<T>` method - thus you would use `Colliider collider = GetComponent<Collider>();`

Comment: where need to be placed exactly?

Comment: @John - try:

`Vector3 worldPosition = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.center + Vector3.up * collider.bounds.size.y * 0.5f;`

Notice the capital `C`